# Check-out a Display Template, how do I edit file

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

When I check out a display template file, where can I get access to this from file explorer? I feel like I have done this before but I can't remember how to do it. If I copy the link that appears in the hover card it just opens in IE as a normal SharePoint page.

I want to be able to open it from File Explorer into NotePad or an HTML editor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that the `Default open behavior for browser-enabled documents:` is set to `Open in the client application`

- library Setting > Advanced Setting > Opening Documents in the Browser.

[image]

Now when clicking on the file it should be opened based on its type at the appropriate client application, if it's `txt` it will be opened in notepad ...etc

**In case,** you still not able to open the file in the client application, you can open the library as windows file explorer.

- From the above ribbon, > click on `Open With Explorer`

[image]

> **Note:**
>
> - In case `Open With Explorer` is disabled so you are using a browser other than IE.
> - In case you are using IE and the `Open With Explorer` is enabled but you get an error. so check [We’re having a problem opening this
>     location in file explorer, add this website to your trusted sites
>     list and try again](https://blog.devoworx.net/2015/03/23/were-having-a-problem-opening-this-location-in-file-explorer-add-this-web-site-to-your-trusted-sites-list-and-try-again/)

**Update to above when dealing with Display Templates (not regular documents):**

The problem  was how to get the ribbon to appear for the display templates to be able to get the "Open with Explorer" option.

If you go to Design Manager > Edit Display Templates > Select the ellipsis ... next to the template, a hover card appears with the URL of the location of the templates. Copy this into address bar in the browser. This shows a list of all display template files.  Select the checkbox next to the template you want to edit, then in the "Library" tab of the ribbon "Open With Explorer". This then allows you to get access to the files in SharePoint as if they are in a Windows folder.

Comment: The problem is I don't see this toolbar when using Design Manager > Edit Display Templates > [Select the template elipsis...] > Advanced > Check-out.

Comment: your question title didn't match with question body ?!! in question body you asked to open checked out file in file explorer ? could you add more details about what exactly need ?!

Comment: Title says Check-out a Display Template? What's the point of checking out if I can't check it in? I've modified the question to emphasize the file is a display template.